# How does the react-native live reload works in Android?

Tags: android, react-native

I tried to find this information in the official documentation but had no luck.

How does the the live reload feature in ReactNative work for Android? When I make a change in my JS code is the whole JS bundle automatically replaced by a new version? Or this only happens when I reload the app?

Which component is responsible for communicating the JS code to native part of ReactNative?

If I define in my build.gradle file a task that copies the JSBundle to the assets folder, how it gets updated when I reload the app using the dev menu?

Thanks